# UICollectionView error using Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am getting this error, trying to use a UICollectionView in Swift:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell ((null))
```

But I think I am registering the cell:

1. ViewDidLoad:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("CollectionCell"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CELL")
   }
   ```
2. cellForItemAtIndexPath:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
   {
      var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionCell

       cell.titleLabel.text="cellText"
       return cell
   }
   ```

and the cell class:

```
    class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell
    {

        @IBOutlet var titleLabel : UILabel
        init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
        {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        } 
     }
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to pass your sub-class of UICollectionViewCell, in the Swift style, to registerClass:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CELL")
```

Comment: Thanks! Progress, Now I get an "use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)", but I'm getting there!

Comment: That this solves.. init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) } Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

If your are not using any custom class just use in ViewDidLoad

```
myCollectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myCollectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

is the code recommended. Worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"CELL")`

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Changing as you suggest results in the following console output: 0x1001bffeb:  leaq   0x16067(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1001bfff2:  movq   %rax, 0x77c67(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1001bfff9:  int3   
0x1001bfffa:  nopw   (%rax,%rax)

Answer (score 1):

For your Cell:

```
class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
@IBOutlet var titleLabel : UILabel
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

For your ViewController:

```
import UIKit
class NextViewController: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView
var ListArray=NSMutableArray()
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

 var nipName=UINib(nibName: "GalleryCell", bundle:nil)
collectionView.registerNib(nipName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL")

for i in 0..70
{
     ListArray .addObject("C: \(i)")
}
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section:Int)->Int
{
    return ListArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath      indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
{
    var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GalleryCell
   cell.titleLabel.text="\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item))"
   return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout  collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
return CGSizeMake(66, 58)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to stick with registerClass rather than registerNib.

Comment: But I'll keep this for next time.. +1